# How to increment/decrement the counter on Icon click and display the count without refreshing all Items

Tags: flutter

The output that I am getting is displayed in the picture:

[image: screenshot]

I wish to increment/decrement the counter on Icon click and display the count of a specific Item. However, On clicking, the counts of all items (generated from the DB using Future builder) are getting refreshed and all the counts are getting updated.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Pollwall extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PollwallState createState() => _PollwallState();
}

class _PollwallState extends State<Pollwall> {
      
  int _itemCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  _fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get('My Cloud IP Address');
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

    return jsonData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        title: new Text("Polling"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          child: new FutureBuilder(
              future: _fetchData(), // a Future<String> or null
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ));
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: new Text('Error ${snapshot.error}'),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 8.0, 5.0, 8.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            var parsedDate =
                                DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index]["Date"]);

                            return Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                              child: new Card(
                                  color: Colors.teal[600],
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ListTile(
                                        title: new Text(
                                          timeAgo(parsedDate),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 12.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          _itemCount != 0
                                              ? new IconButton(
                                                  icon: new Icon(Icons.remove),
                                                  onPressed: () => setState(
                                                      () => _itemCount--),
                                                )
                                              : new Container(),
                                          new Text(_itemCount.toString()),
                                          new IconButton(
                                              icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
                                              onPressed: () =>
                                                  setState(() => _itemCount++))
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                            );

                            // );
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  
}
```

I used Cards for Displaying the Items data. If the user clicks add ICON only that specific count should be updated.

Comment: Try using change notifier.

Comment: If there is list of counter widgets, then you have to maintain a counter variable (or `List` of count) for each. Why there is only one `_itemCount` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counter is reset because the _itemCount variable is in the _PollwallState class. You need to create a class for item, which will have its own _itemCount variable.

Pollwall widget:

```
class _PollwallState extends StatelessWidget {

  _fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get('My Cloud IP Address');
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    return jsonData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        title: new Text("Polling"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          child: new FutureBuilder(
              future: _fetchData(), // a Future<String> or null
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ));
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: new Text('Error ${snapshot.error}'),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 8.0, 5.0, 8.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index]["Date"]);
                            return PollwallItem(parsedDate: parsedDate);
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Item widget:

```
class PollwallItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final var parsedDate;

  const PollwallItem({Key key, this.parsedDate}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PollwallItemState createState() => _PollwallItemState();
}

class _PollwallItemState extends State<PollwallItem> {
  int _itemCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
        child: new Card(
         color: Colors.teal[600],
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: new Text(timeAgo(widget.parsedDate),
                    style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.white,
                       fontSize: 12.0,
                     ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                   _itemCount != 0
                    new IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(Icons.remove),
                       onPressed: () => setState(
                        () => _itemCount--),
                       )
                    : new Container(),
                      new Text(_itemCount.toString()),
                        new IconButton(
                          icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
                            onPressed: () =>
                             setState(() => _itemCount++))
                   ],
                ),
              ],
            )),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for u r response...var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index]["Date"]); The var parsed Date is not accessible in _PollwallItemState class. Which i need to pass to timeAgo(parsedDate) method. I tried with constructor also. But no luck.

Comment: I added passing the parsedDate parameter. Please see updated code